# Segmentation fault with flex bison and yyparse

Tags: c, gcc, bison, lex

I was trying to implement flex and bison when this loop returned segmentation fault whith core dumped
With the first file it worked fine but the next file crashed and printed into terminal segmentation fault.

```
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;

    if ((dir = opendir ("./Corpus")) != NULL) 
    {
      while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) 
      { 
        if ((strcmp(ent->d_name,".") != 0) && (strcmp(ent->d_name,"..") != 0))
         {
            printf("%s\n",ent->d_name);
            yyin = fopen(ent->d_name,"r");
            yyparse();


        } 

      }

      closedir (dir);
    } 
    else 
    {
      // could not open directory 
      perror ("");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

Comment: The lexer and parser are statefull, you can't just switch file that easily and start parsing that. Instead I suggest you read the [FLEX manual](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/), which contains examples on how to switch files.

Comment: But I used it not in a loop and it worked.

Comment: "But I used it not in a loop and it worked". This means nothing. Bison and flex are not built with this usage in mind. You need to jump through several hoops to make them work the second time around.

Comment: I *think* on the bison side you need to at least call `yyrestart()` before each subsequent run. No idea about the flex side.

Comment: @n.m.: `bison` does not do any I/O at all. It just handles tokens. And `flex` does not require you to call `yyrestart` to change files after reading an EOF.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Actually, you can. At least from flex's perspective, you can (see quote from Flex manual in my answer); if your scanner or parser depend on global state, you may need to do something else.

Comment: @rici My mistake, yyrestart() has nothing to do with bison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a reasonably recent version of `flex`, there is nothing wrong with switching input files in the way you do it. However, without seeing more code, it is impossible to know for certain what the problem is.

One obvious problem is that you do not check the value of `yyin` after the call to `fopen`. If the open fails (which is likely, see below), then `yyin` will be `NULL` and that will certainly create a segfault when `flex` attempts to read.

Also, you don't seem to be closing `yyin`, which will leak file descriptors. This should not be a problem on the second file, but it will eventually cause the open to fail for lack of file descriptors.

The problem with the `fopen` is that `ent->d_name` is just the basename of the file, without any path. So `fopen` will search for the file in the current working directory. However, the directory being read is `./Corpus`, which is a subdirectory; unless the file is duplicated between Corpus and the main directory, the file will not be found.

For the benefit of commentators, the [Flex manual](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Generated-Scanner.html#index-EOF-and-yyrestart_0028_0029) states:

> If the scanner reaches an end-of-file, subsequent calls are undefined unless either yyin is pointed at a new input file (in which case scanning continues from that file)… Essentially there is no difference between just assigning yyin to a new input file or using yyrestart() to do so; the latter is available for compatibility with previous versions of flex, and because it can be used to switch input files in the middle of scanning.

It is also possible that the segfault is independent of file handling. It would be best to use a debugger to determine where exactly the segfault occurs.